# Distorted transparent PNG images in RDLC PDF reports

Tags: image, pdf, report, rdlc, transparent

I have a  RDLC report with a transparent PNG image in the header.
When I create the PDF of the report, the image is getting distorted.
Is there any way to get the correct image instead of distorted image in PDF report?

Answer (score 3):

Use JPEG or JIF instead of using PNG images for report.

Comment: why? there is no explanation in the answer about the problem. Also, the user is asking for transparent images.